# Chaining to multiple parallel subgraph matches

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a graph with multiple workout nodes.  Each workout node has relationships to multiple media, workout type, and body focus nodes.

The following individual queries all work as intended and give the expected results:

1) Return set of workouts and the media for each:

`MATCH (w:Workout)-[:hasMedia]->(m:Media) RETURN w.name as workout, collect(m.url) AS media`

2) Return set of workouts and the workout types for each:

`MATCH (w:Workout)-[:hasConcept]->(wt:Concept)-[:ofType]->(Category{name:"training"}) RETURN w.name AS workout, collect(wt.name) AS workoutType`

3) Return set of workouts and the body focuses for each:

`MATCH (w:Workout)-[:hasConcept]->(bf:Concept)-[:ofType]->(Category{name:"bodyfocus"}) RETURN w.name AS workout, collect(bf.name) AS bodyFocus`

Furthermore, I have a set of People nodes with relationships to workouts.

The following query works as intended and gives the expected results:

A) Return set of workouts relevant to a particular person and why (score, evidence):

`MATCH (Person{personId:"1028"})-[r:hasAffinity]->(c:Concept)<-[s]-(w:Workout) RETURN sum(toFloat(r.score)*toFloat(s.score))/count(c) AS score, w.name AS workout, collect({text:c.name, polarity:r.score, evidenceId:c.name}) AS evidence`

What I'm trying to do (and failing miserably) is arrive at a single compound query that answers the following: "return the set of relevant workouts for a person, with score, evidence, media, workout types, and body focuses for each workout".

It seems like I want :  MATCH {A's path} WITH w MATCH w-{rest of 1's path}, w-{rest of 2's path}, w-{rest of 3's path} RETURN {A's stuff}, {1's stuff}, {2's stuff}, {3's stuff}

... but I can't get that to work (and as a newbie could be wrong about the approach anyway).  Help?

Comment: Can you draw your network? Would make it much easier too understand what kind of query you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you need to combine everything in one query:

```
// get the Workouts of a Person via the Concept
MATCH (p:Person {personId:"1028"})-[r:hasAffinity]->(c:Concept)<-[s]-(w:Workout)

// take the Person and Workout to the next step, calculate score and collect evidence
WITH DISTINCT p, w, sum(toFloat(r.score)*toFloat(s.score))/count(c) AS score, 
     collect({text:c.name, polarity:r.score, evidenceId:c.name}) AS evidence

// Match everything else for the workout
MATCH (w)-[:hasConcept]->(wt:Concept)-[:ofType]->(:Category {name:"training"})
MATCH (w)-[:hasConcept]->(bf:Concept)-[:ofType]->(:Category {name:"bodyfocus"})
MATCH (w)-[:hasMedia]->(m:Media)

// Return everything (score and evidence are available from the WITH statement)
RETURN p.personID, w.name AS workout, collect(wt.name) AS workoutType, 
    collect(bf.name) AS bodyFocus, collect(m.url) AS media, score, evidence
```